# Task specific result_serializer in Celery

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

`celery.conf.update(result_serializer='pickle')` uses pickle for serializing results generated by Celery tasks. Is there a way to tell which serializer (JSON, pickle, etc...) to be used at the individual task level?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that is not possible.